# Gnu Octave. Операция "разность" выдает неверное значение

Tags: математика, матрицы, octave

Мне нужно из матрицы `t` вычесть `0.3`
Матрица выглядит следующим образом:

```
t =

 Columns 1 through 9:

          0     0.1000     0.2000     0.3000     0.4000     0.5000     0.6000     0.7000     0.8000

 Columns 10 through 18:

     0.9000     1.0000     1.1000     1.2000     1.3000     1.4000     1.5000     1.6000     1.7000

 Columns 19 through 27:

     1.8000     1.9000     2.0000     2.1000     2.2000     2.3000     2.4000     2.5000     2.6000

 Columns 28 through 36:

     2.7000     2.8000     2.9000     3.0000     3.1000     3.2000     3.3000     3.4000     3.5000

 Columns 37 through 45:

     3.6000     3.7000     3.8000     3.9000     4.0000     4.1000     4.2000     4.3000     4.4000

 Columns 46 through 54:

     4.5000     4.6000     4.7000     4.8000     4.9000     5.0000     5.1000     5.2000     5.3000

 Columns 55 through 63:

     5.4000     5.5000     5.6000     5.7000     5.8000     5.9000     6.0000     6.1000     6.2000

 Columns 64 through 72:

     6.3000     6.4000     6.5000     6.6000     6.7000     6.8000     6.9000     7.0000     7.1000

 Columns 73 through 81:

     7.2000     7.3000     7.4000     7.5000     7.6000     7.7000     7.8000     7.9000     8.0000

 Columns 82 through 90:

     8.1000     8.2000     8.3000     8.4000     8.5000     8.6000     8.7000     8.8000     8.9000

 Columns 91 through 99:

     9.0000     9.1000     9.2000     9.3000     9.4000     9.5000     9.6000     9.7000     9.8000

 Columns 100 and 101:

     9.9000    10.0000
```

На выходе операции `t - 0.3` следующая матрица:

```
>> t - 0.3
ans =

 Columns 1 through 7:

  -3.0000e-01  -2.0000e-01  -1.0000e-01   5.5511e-17   1.0000e-01   2.0000e-01   3.0000e-01

 Columns 8 through 14:

   4.0000e-01   5.0000e-01   6.0000e-01   7.0000e-01   8.0000e-01   9.0000e-01   1.0000e+00

 Columns 15 through 21:

   1.1000e+00   1.2000e+00   1.3000e+00   1.4000e+00   1.5000e+00   1.6000e+00   1.7000e+00

 Columns 22 through 28:

   1.8000e+00   1.9000e+00   2.0000e+00   2.1000e+00   2.2000e+00   2.3000e+00   2.4000e+00

 Columns 29 through 35:

   2.5000e+00   2.6000e+00   2.7000e+00   2.8000e+00   2.9000e+00   3.0000e+00   3.1000e+00

 Columns 36 through 42:

   3.2000e+00   3.3000e+00   3.4000e+00   3.5000e+00   3.6000e+00   3.7000e+00   3.8000e+00

 Columns 43 through 49:

   3.9000e+00   4.0000e+00   4.1000e+00   4.2000e+00   4.3000e+00   4.4000e+00   4.5000e+00

 Columns 50 through 56:

   4.6000e+00   4.7000e+00   4.8000e+00   4.9000e+00   5.0000e+00   5.1000e+00   5.2000e+00

 Columns 57 through 63:

   5.3000e+00   5.4000e+00   5.5000e+00   5.6000e+00   5.7000e+00   5.8000e+00   5.9000e+00

 Columns 64 through 70:

   6.0000e+00   6.1000e+00   6.2000e+00   6.3000e+00   6.4000e+00   6.5000e+00   6.6000e+00

 Columns 71 through 77:

   6.7000e+00   6.8000e+00   6.9000e+00   7.0000e+00   7.1000e+00   7.2000e+00   7.3000e+00

 Columns 78 through 84:

   7.4000e+00   7.5000e+00   7.6000e+00   7.7000e+00   7.8000e+00   7.9000e+00   8.0000e+00

 Columns 85 through 91:

   8.1000e+00   8.2000e+00   8.3000e+00   8.4000e+00   8.5000e+00   8.6000e+00   8.7000e+00

 Columns 92 through 98:

   8.8000e+00   8.9000e+00   9.0000e+00   9.1000e+00   9.2000e+00   9.3000e+00   9.4000e+00

 Columns 99 through 101:

   9.5000e+00   9.6000e+00   9.7000e+00
```

Почему получаются эти значения и как исправить это?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код для создания матрицы. Без полного примера трудно разобраться.